# Coupling in Elastic Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, coupling

We are thinking of doing coupling in the items stored in Elastic Search. While indexing we index the coupling information of the item in the item doc. Is there a way to query the Elastic search so that the coupled items come together in the result?

For eg:

```
item1 = {
    ...
    coupled_item: item2
    ...
}

item2 = {
    ...
    coupled_item: item1
    ...
}

query_result = [item3, item6, item1, item2, item4, item5]
```

### Approach 1

One of the approaches which we thought was to add a `score` key in the item doc and set the score of the coupled products as equal and then while querying, sort it by that score.

#### Cons

We are already doing the sorting using this technique, we do not want to hinder that order we just want to insert the coupled item from its place to right below the item.

### Approach 2

The other approach we thought was to query all the items from the ES and then handle it through the code.

#### Cons

Cons are that this is not the optimal solution plus we also need to handle the pagination ourselves in this case.

Is there a feature provided by Elastic Search to handle coupling internally. If not then is there any other way we can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Coupled(dependant) documents can be duplicated inside each other.

```
    item1 = {
        id: item1
        coupled_item: {
            id: item2 
        }
        ...
    }

    item2 = {
        id: item2
        coupled_item: {
            id: item1 
        }
        ...
    }

es_query_result = [item1 {item2}, item3 {item4}, item5 {item6}]

application_flattened_result = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6]
```

This will add some challenges to document writes because now two documents will get updated with two requests, but can be done. Additionally, pagination of search query can get tricky as well.

Only internally supported feature, that I know, that comes close enough is - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html